# How to disable coalescing of log messages in OS X?

Tags: command-line, console

I've been using Console to debug some things on my Mac, and I keep seeing `--- last message repeated one time ---` in the log.  Apparently it's [not really essential](http://www.ossec.net/dcid/?p=119), and you can turn it off on the command line with the -dup_delay switch on syslogd (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/syslogd.8.html)).  But how do I do that so it turns it off in the Console app?  I don't want to start syslogd again, I just want to change a setting on the currently running process.

Answer (score 1):

The Console application is simply reading the log files.  I suspect running syslogd with that flag will cure your problem, as syslogd will then write the log files differently..